# How to edit personal contact form e-mail content - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes, emails

I looked everywhere in my admin for this. Can it be achieved via the admin panel or do I have to make a custom module?

I can't seem to find an adequate code snippet on Drupal Answers. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this can be done through the admin panel though it is quite easy through a module using hook_mail_alter()

if it is the drupal core contact form then use this in YOUR_MODULE.module

```
function YOUR_MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {
    //MODIFY THE MESSAGE HERE
  }
}
```

(always remember to clear caches after adding a hook)

It is a good idea to get the devel module and add

```
dpm($message);
```

see what the variables are that you want to modify and enjoy.